# Get regexp math in mysql select

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have table with this rows:**

```
title1|mail@mail.com-adsasd

title2|mail@mail.com

title3|mail@mail.com- asdasdasd

title4|asdasd mail@mail.com

...

titleN|dasdasd- mail@mail.com
```

---

How to get all emails from `contact` field **without excess text**? I need only emails.

**My query for determination emails in `contact` field:**

```
SELECT title, contact
FROM table
WHERE contact REGEXP  '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]{2,}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no regexp extraction function in mysql,
you have to clean your data before inserting it to table.